# Python: find if a given regular expression is present in a file

Tags: python, regex

I want to if a pattern exists in a very large file. A brute force technique would be:

```
match = re.findall("xyz", text)
    if(len(match) > 0):
        print 'Match found'
```

The `findall` finds all the matches. Is there any way to terminate just after first instance is found?

Comment: Use `re.search` to find only the first instance.

Comment: Will `if xyz in text` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If hwnd's solution doens't work for you, try `re.finditer()`. It returns an iterator.  If you use `next()` to examine the first match, it won't scan for any more matches -- you'll see only the first.

### source

```
import re

m = re.finditer( 'beer', open('zfind.py').read() ).next()
print m and m.group(0)
```

### output

```
beer
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a function.

```
def isitthere(file_to_check, pattern):
    with open(file_to_check, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if pattern in line:
                return True    #return on first match stops the iteration
            else:
                continue
    return False

if isitthere(file_to_check, pattern):
    print 'Match Found!'
```

or using re.search:

```
def isitthere(file_to_check, pattern):
    with open(file_to_check, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            if re.search(pattern, line) != None:
                return True          #return on first match stops the iteration
            else:
                continue
    return False

if isitthere(file_to_check, pattern):
    print 'Match Found!'
```